# Yamaha Bass keys accompaniment in Ableton live

Tags: chords, ableton-live, accompaniment

My piano teacher was telling me that when he turns on the accompaniment and when you are playing chords, when you hold the previous black key you get the minor chord for that. Example if i wanted to play the Eminor i hold E and d# to get the chord. How can i set it up in ableton live. I know it should be one of the midi effects, but i do not know which one. This happens in yamaha keyboards.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yamaha 'ABC' method is proprietary [& iirc patented] system, so you won't find exactly the same algorithms used in other devices or software.

The method you are referring to is the 'easy-play' version of ABC. It uses a different, much simpler but less musically-accurate shorthand to play a much smaller selection of chord types [only major/mnior, 7th, iirc]. It really isn't a system you ought to use to learn how to play, it's more for 'fun.

The 'full' version of ABC requires you to state the chord you wish quite clearly; giving the system a root, 3rd, 5th + any flavour notes, before it will follow you accurately.

For instance,
if you press just C it will play Unison... nothing but C's
if you add an E above it will play C Major
adding an A above, it would assume A minor, even though C is the lowest note
so to get C6 you would need to add G as well.

*Source:* I used to actually program those built-in styles for a living, long time ago ;)

Comment: Could you elaborate on your third para..? Are you also telling that there is nothing like that in ableton and i have to make a device using max for live or something.?

Comment: I've added an example to the answer, & yes, afaik, you'd need to make something yourself to do that type of input. It might have a version of the 'full' ABC built-in, but less likely the simplified one.